# Problems installing or compiling seeks Debian Squeeze

Tags: installation, debian

I'm trying to install (and compile but the error is due to the same problem in the end) SeekS on my Debian Squeeze (Linux vserver 2.6.32-5-vserver-amd64)

Here is the output I get :

```
root@vserver:~/seeks# apt-get install seeks 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 seeks : Depends: libevent-2.0-5 (>= 2.0.10-stable) but it is not installable
         Depends: libicu48 (>= 4.8-1) but it is not installable
         Depends: libopencv-calib3d2.3 but it is not installable
         Depends: libopencv-contrib2.3 but it is not installable
         Depends: libopencv-core2.3 but it is not installable
         Depends: libopencv-features2d2.3 but it is not installable
         Depends: libopencv-flann2.3 but it is not installable
         Depends: libopencv-highgui2.3 but it is not installable
         Depends: libopencv-imgproc2.3 but it is not installable
         Depends: libopencv-legacy2.3 but it is not installable
         Depends: libopencv-ml2.3 but it is not installable
         Depends: libopencv-objdetect2.3 but it is not installable
         Depends: libopencv-video2.3 but it is not installable
         Depends: libpcre3 (>= 8.10) but 8.02-1.1 is to be installed
         Depends: libprotobuf7 but it is not installable
         Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 4.6) but 4.4.5-8 is to be installed
         Depends: libtokyocabinet9 (>= 1.4.47) but it is not installable
E: Broken packages
```

Does anybody know how to resolve it? I checked my repertories and everything seems okay.

Thank you in advance

Comment: please also post the contents of your /etc/apt/sources.list and everything in /etc/apt/sources.list.d

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know where you got that package, but it's clear that its
dependencies are not satisfiable from Debian/squeeze. Take `libicu48`,
for example:

```
$ rmadison libicu48
 libicu48 | 4.8.1.1-8 | wheezy | amd64, armel, armhf, i386, ia64, kfreebsd-amd64, kfreebsd-i386, mips, mipsel, powerpc, s390, s390x, sparc
 libicu48 | 4.8.1.1-8 | sid    | amd64, armel, armhf, hurd-i386, i386, ia64, kfreebsd-amd64, kfreebsd-i386, mips, mipsel, powerpc, s390, s390x, sparc
```

The source file for `libicu48` is `icu`, let's go looking for that:

```
$ rmadison icu
 icu | 4.4.1-8   | squeeze-security | source
 icu | 4.4.1-8   | squeeze          | source
 icu | 4.8.1.1-8 | wheezy           | source
 icu | 4.8.1.1-8 | sid              | source
```

Looks like you are going to have to build the package from source.
`libstdc++`, `libicu*`, `libevent*`, `libpcre3` are probably not going
to be much of a problem.